# Java Connect to MySQL via PHP-Script

Tags: java, php, mysql

As im only able to use the DB from my Webhoster through a PHP-Script im wondering how im making the connection to the script workable

PHP:

```
<?php
$query=$_POST["query"];
echo" Query = ".$query."\n";
if($query){
    $link=mysql_connect("localhost:3306","user","password");
    if($link){
        mysql_select_db("learnEng");
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        if($result){
            while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
                foreach($row as $value){ 
                    echo "\t".$value;
                }
                echo"\n";
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo " MySQL connect failed ! \n";
    }
}else{
    echo " No Query ! \n";
}
exit();
?>
```

Currently im making DB-Connections with Java like this (using H2):

```
Connection conn = null;

    String db = "~/testDB";
    String dbUser = "user";
    String dbPass = "password";

    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://"+h2IP+"/" + db, dbUser, dbPass);
```

After some more research i found that code:

```
HttpURLConnection conn=null;
    try{
        URL url=new URL("http://www.example.net/database.php");
        String agent="Applet";
        String query="query=" + "create table test(name varchar(255), id int);";
        String type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", agent );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", type );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", ""+query.length());

        OutputStream out=conn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(query.getBytes());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while((inputLine=in.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.print(inputLine+"\n");
        };
        in.close();
        int rc = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.print("Response Code = "+rc+"\n");
        String rm=conn.getResponseMessage();
        System.out.print("Response Message = "+rm+"\n");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        conn.disconnect();
    }
```

After executing i get the following response with the php-Code from above in the Eclipse Console:

```
    Query = 
 No Query ! 
Response Code = 200
Response Message = OK
```

May someone be able to tell me what is going on and how to get it to work?

Kind regards
AMC

Comment: You forgot to write: **please write it for me! ! !**

Comment: What you are asking for does not make sense!

Comment: What is the value of h2IP variable ? Most probably hoster has DB on different server but your php tries to connect to localhost:3306

Comment: @AniketSahrawat What the OP asked for happened to me some time ago as well - there are web hosters allowing PHP to access the MySQL database, but no database access from outside. I posted an answer roughly describing my solution.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff That's not a solution but workaround. Also, if this is the situation then you should probably change the host. For me, this is not a good programming practise! I won't go with these kinds of workarounds which force me to learn a new language for just getting a connection of db.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Of course, that's a very special situation that applies only to a small minority of cases. Had I been able to change the hoster easily, I had done it.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat value of h2IP is localhost:8082 as the h2DB is installed on the local machine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation some time ago. The web hoster didn't allow direct access to the mySQL database, but allowed for PHP scripts.

Have a look at [MySQLTunnel](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqltunnel/). It's not JDBC, but HTTP(S) taking the query as URL-encoded "query" parameter and giving the results as JSON. So with the appropriate glue code you can use it instead of a normal JDBC connection.

But before you go that route, be sure to understand the security issues raised by that approach. You don't want the bad guys to get read and write access to your data, do you?

Comment: as there are no data on the Database i think im fine with the risks, Thanks for your Answer Ralf